# I am getting encoded data when I am downloading the image/file

Tags: express, axios, nestjs

I have set up a proxy in my NestJs Application to bypass the CORS restrictions.

The EP for the service is -

`https://api.niftyuat.com/cors?cd=https://google.com`

And it will give me the body of the google home page hence bypassing the CORS restriction.

But the issue is, when I try to download any image or some file, it gives me some kind of encoded input.

`https://api.niftyuat.com/cors?cd=https://niftypm-production-assets-user.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/a895af03-aa9e-4b60-a3b4-54776b240c3e-Screen%20Shot%202021-03-18%20at%2012.03.24%20PM.png`

[image]

I am also sharing my code.

```
    @Controller('cors')
export class CorsController {
  constructor(private readonly corsService: CorsService) { }

 

     @Get()
      async get(@Query('cd') uri: string, @Response() res: ExpressResponse) {
        try {
    
          let url = uri.charAt(0) == '/' ? uri.substring(1) : uri;
    
          const response: AxiosResponse = await axios.get(url, {
            timeout: 5000,
          })
          res.writeHead(200, { ...response.headers })
          res.write(JSON.stringify(response.data))
          res.end()
    
        } catch (error) {
    
          return error.message
        }
    
      }
    
    }
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you taking in a PNG binary, and trying to return it to your user as a JSON string? I could see how that might turn out like this.

Comment: I am trying to return the actual file as it would if we access it directly from the browser

Comment: Right, I'm saying you shouldn't do `JSON.stringify(response.data)`, then.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set `Content-Type` header in response. Set it to 'image/png' or 'image/x-png'.

Comment: I am copying all the headers that I am getting from the initial response here.
`res.writeHead(200, { ...response.headers })`

Comment: I think your service is not working properly, there is a single quote at starting of your page and it seems the whole HTML is escaped for double-quotes. In console also, it says invalid token: Unexpected Syntax Error.